# Hover over menu and select sub menu in java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to hover over a main menu and select a submenu using java selenium, i got it to hover over the menu but cant select the sub menu, if i try to find by linktext i always get the error "does not exist " if i use xpath the says build successful but does not open up the new page.  Here is my code for it so far

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Driver/chromedriver.exe");      
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();       
    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    webDriver.navigate().to("https://www.skiutah.com");

    String NavTo = "DEALS";
    String pathx = "//*[@id=\"top_menu\"]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a" ;
    WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.linkText(NavTo));
    WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(pathx));
    Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
    action.moveToElement(element).perform();
    action.moveToElement(el).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//locate the menu to hover over using its xpath
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Deals"));
//Initiate mouse action using Actions class
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// move the mouse to the earlier identified menu option
builder.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
// wait for max of 5 seconds before proceeding.
// until this submenu is found
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"top_menu\"]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a")));  
//identify menu option from the resulting menu display and click
WebElement menuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"top_menu\"]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a"));
menuOption.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
This works for me first time, but if repeated for other menu item then it cant find or something.

WebElement menu =  driver.findElement(By.your_locator);
WebElement sub_menu =  driver.findElement(By.your_locator);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(sub_menu).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

In WebDriver we have given option to control `Mouse` events. Try this piece of code. This should serve the purpose.

```
driver.get("https://www.skiutah.com/");
WebElement deals = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Deals']"));
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) deals;
mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
WebElement beginner = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Beginner']"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(beginner));
Locatable clickItem = (Locatable) beginner;
mouse.mouseDown(clickItem.getCoordinates());
mouse.mouseUp(clickItem.getCoordinates());
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 1):

To use mouse over action we need to use build.perform. It is called as action chaining which ensure that its perform actions together at the end. Or you can swap the line as below and it should work for you. I tried looks good.

```
String NavTo = "DEALS";
String pathx = "//*[@id=\"top_menu\"]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a" ;
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.linkText(NavTo));
WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(pathx));
Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
action.moveToElement(el).click();
String NavTo = "DEALS";
String pathx = "//*[@id=\"top_menu\"]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a" ;
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.linkText(NavTo));
WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(pathx));
Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
action.moveToElement(el).click();
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are hovering and clicking on a sub-menu is not seems correct.

You haven't shared your `html` so its little bit tedious to check element you have located are correct or not. If all fine, Try following code which might help you -

```
WebElement menu =  driver.findElement(By.your_locator);
WebElement sub_menu =  driver.findElement(By.your_locator);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(sub_menu).click().build().perform();
```

**Explaination :-**

Here `build()` method is used to compile all the list of actions into a single step and ready to be performed

Answer (score 0):

First Mousehover to the main menu and then click any of the submenus.

```
WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='top_menu']/ul/li[4]/a"))));
Actions mousehover = new Actions(driver);
mousehover.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Deals"))).build().perform();
Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Deals"))));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Deals")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to 'click' the sub-menu. Need to mouse over on to the main menu and it takes few seconds to load the sub-menu. then i need to locate the sub-menu and click it.
Here is the code which i used

```
 Actions ac = new Actions(dr);  
 WebElement we = dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ddtopmenubar']/ul/li[1]/a"));
 ac.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dr, 5); 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dataingestionsubmenu']/li[2]/a")));
 WebElement e= dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dataingestionsubmenu']/li[2]/a"));
 e.click();
```

but it doesn't seems to work out.

getting exception as : 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: performActions
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

when i do the same in debug mode, then i'm able to click submenu.

Comment: even I tried this code to : WebElement menu =  driver.findElement(By.your_locator);
WebElement sub_menu =  driver.findElement(By.your_locator);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(sub_menu).click().build().perform();